# Solution to hibernate nonuniqueobjectexception

Tags: hibernate

My Code is

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public void saveIndent(StockRequisitionCumIssue stockRequisitionCumIssue,
    List<StockRequisitionCumIssueDetail> srciDetails,
    List<StockRequisitionCumIssueDetail> removedObjects) {

    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().clear();
    for (StockRequisitionCumIssueDetail srciDetail : removedObjects) {
        objectLoader.delete(StockRequisitionCumIssueDetail.class, srciDetail);
    }

    objectLoader.save(StockRequisitionCumIssue.class, stockRequisitionCumIssue);

    for (StockRequisitionCumIssueDetail srciDetail : srciDetails) {

        srciDetail.setStockRequisitionCumIssue(stockRequisitionCumIssue);
        objectLoader.save(StockRequisitionCumIssueDetail.class, srciDetail);

        item.setOpeningQuantity(item.getOpeningQuantity().subtract(srciDetail.getQuantityIssued()));
        item.setTotalValuation(item.getOpeningQuantity().multiply(item.getStandardCost()));
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().update(item);
        objectLoader.save(Item.class, item);
    }
}
```

I am trying to update the item Object.But it is not allowing me to update the same item twice.It is throwing a hibernate nonuniqueobjectexception.Please help me if you have a solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to persist the item object twice. can you clarify the role of objectLoader ?

Comment: objectLoader.save is just to save the object.It can save one object at a time.I am getting the exception only when I am trying to save the same item twice.

Comment: I assume your save() method calls the save() method from your session object? This method tries to persist a NEW instance each time (see my answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure where exactly you get the exception, but if you try to save (I assumed this is what ObjectLoader.save() does..) the same object multiple times, Hibernate will throw an exception as object with the identifier (PK) already exists. 
Use saveOrUpdate instead or just removed this line as the update should already have done the work.